# Session does not work between pages

Tags: php, session, post

I have this problem. Session does not work when I use with $_POST. If I add 63 manualy it will works across pages. I can see the output 63.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = 63;
echo $_SESSION['name'] ;
```

but this below won't work when I switch between pages. The $row['id'] output is also 63.

```
$cari = "SELECT  id FROM dns_soa WHERE `origin` = '".$_POST['origin']."'";
$keputusan = mysql_query($cari);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($keputusan);   

$_SESSION['name'] = $row['id'];
echo $_SESSION['name'] ;
```

When I go to 2nd pages I can see the output but when I went back to 1st pages the output is gone. Any idea?

Comment: do you have session_start, before you use the sessions on every page you want to use the session?

Comment: yes. Weirds when I manually initialize 63 the output is shown in both pages.

Comment: you don't check the query actully works. And its vulnerable to sql injection attack.

Comment: I echo the $row['id'] and the output is 63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you are coming back it will again set the session variable, as this time you don't have the $_POST[origin] variable that leads to $row['id']="" and the session variable also NULL...

What you should do is..

```
$cari = "SELECT  id FROM dns_soa WHERE `origin` = '".$_POST['origin']."'";
$keputusan = mysql_query($cari);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($keputusan);   

if(!isset($_SESSION['name']))
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['id'];

echo $_SESSION['name'] ;
```

Comment: Typing in iPad sucks. I become slow.

Answer (score 1):

When you **go back** to the page where you have used `$_POST`, `$_POST` becomes empty, unless your browser posts it again. So the SQL query returns no result. Hence, `$_SESSION['name']`  becomes empty.

Also make sure you have invoked `session_start` on every page before using `$_SESSION`

Comment: Actually I thought the same thing too. Thanks for trying to help me mate :)